# Random numbers correlation

Tags: random, random-walk, correlation

I was doing some random number generator testing when I noticed something about `ran1` generator from *Numerical Recepies*. I generated numbers in range $\left<2.5,7.5\right>$ and wanted to check the randomness of the number series by calculating the sum of products of near neighbours
    \begin{equation}C\left(k\right)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}r_ir_{i+k}
  \tag{1}
\label{eq:sum}
 \end{equation}
    for different values of $k$. For large $N$ we can approximate the sum \eqref{eq:sum} with integral
    \begin{equation} \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}r_ir_{i+k} \approx \int_{2.5}^{7.5}dx \int_{2.5}^{7.5}dyP\left(x,y\right)xy
\tag{2}
  \label{eq:int}
 \end{equation}
    $P\left(x,y\right)dxdy$  is the probability of getting numbers in intervals $\left<x,x+dx\right>$ and $\left<y,y+dy\right>$, now we have:
    \begin{equation}
  \int_{2.5}^{7.5}dx \int_{2.5}^{7.5}dyP\left(x,y\right) = 1
  \tag{3}
        \label{eq:norm}
 \end{equation}
    If the distribution given by the generator is uniform, then $P=const.$ and we can calculate it using equation \eqref{eq:norm}.
    \begin{equation}  1=P\int_{2.5}^{7.5}dx \int_{2.5}^{7.5}dy = 25P\Longrightarrow P=\frac{1}{25}\end{equation}
    Now we plug this into \eqref{eq:int} and get
    \begin{equation}
 \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}r_ir_{i+k} \approx 25
 \label{eq:aprox}
 \end{equation}
Additionally, if the numbers are really random, the deviation from this equation should depend on $N$ as $1/\sqrt N$. So I calculated this for different values of $k$ and noticed that the results are $k$-independent.
[image: graph 1]
[image: graph 2]

I am not sure what this means. The sum represents a correlation function. How can correlation of elements of a series be the same for 1st and $n$th neighbours?

**EDIT** Here is the same calculation for a different generator. [rand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NBuJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the numbers are random, the correlation between pairs at any distance should be independent of the distance.  That is not surprising.  When you convert the sum to the integral, you should say $$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}r_ir_{i+k} \approx \int_{2.5}^{7.5}x\ dx \int_{2.5}^{7.5}y\ dyP\left(x,y\right)xy
$$
The way you did it the integral doesn't change if you change the range to $(100,105)$ but the product of two elements has to get much larger.

Comment: I don't think so... The solution of the integral, as I did it, with arbitrary boundaries, say $a$ to $b$ is $\int_{a}^{b}dx \int_{a}^{b}dyP\left(x,y\right)xy=\frac{1}{25}\frac{1}{4}\left(b^2-a^2\right) ^2$ which is very much range-dependant.

Comment: As for the randomness, you are saying that this actually means the generator is "good". I did the same test with \texttt{rand} from C-library and the results were different - the $\sqrt N$ dependence was there, but the sum was changing as I changed $k$. Do you think this means that rand is "less random" than ran1? (I know it really is, but is this a way to show it?) I added the graph in the question.

Comment: A proper generator should have no correlation between sequential random numbers, so your product should be independent of the spacing.  As Numerical Recipes says in the text, many of these generators are linear congruential generators which exhibit sequential correlation.  If the generator exhibits sequential correlations, it is a bad generator for some purposes, though it may be useful for others.